# Material-UI: How to "grow" a dialog from a given position?

Tags: animation, material-ui

I have a Dialog which is triggered by clicking on a specific `div` on my page.

How can I change the default fade-in animation of the dialog to one, which kind of grows out of the `div` element which was clicked?

Answer (score 2):

You should check out [CSS3 transitions](https://www.webdesignerdepot.com/2014/05/8-simple-css3-transitions-that-will-wow-your-users/). In your Material-UI app, you'll want to define a class in your styles object, then add it conditionally in your `Dialog`'s `className` prop when you click on the `div`.

So you'd want something like (using Hooks syntax):

Outside component:

```
const useStyles = makeStyles({
  openDialog: {
    /* your transition CSS here */
  }
});
```

Component body:

```
const {openDialog} = useStyles();
const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
```

And in JSX:

```
<div onClick={() => setOpen(true)}>Div content</div>
<Dialog className={open && openDialog}>Dialog content</Dialog>
```

Material-UI also has [Transitions](https://material-ui.com/utils/transitions/) components you can use.